# Live Connection from Javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, connection

Is there a way to have a live connection (like for a chat server) with a server using only HTML(5)/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently FF4, Chrome, and Safari all support [Web Sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/).

Here's a [firefox example](http://bohuco.net/blog/2010/07/html5-websockets-example/), although I'm not sure the spec is completely finalized yet.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of HTTP (only clients can start requests), you would need a "Push" server (aka Comet) on the server-side. You'd still only need JS on the client. See:

- [HTTP Streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming) for an explanation of the technology
- [APE: Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/) for usable implementation
- [Comet Daily](http://cometdaily.com/about/) for news on Comet

This can also be implemented with a [periodic refresh](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh) (polling) if you can't install a Comet engine on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. AJAX and some server code to handle messages updates is all you need to create just such a system. As @NullUserException noted, something like Comet might make this easier.

Comment: ajax just loads pages, I need a truly live "socket" connection.

Comment: You could emulate it. You don't need a live socket to do a chat client. Look at facebook chat; the order of messages isn't guaranteed, but that's because it shows the user's post as soon as they hit enter, rather than when the response returns.

Comment: And ajax doesn't just "load pages". It would allow you to make network requests to some server application which would manage reads and writes of the current chat session.

Comment: I'm trying to make a virtual world without using flash or any downloads.

Comment: And? If you want to do something like an MMO, you could buffer the actions of other players on the screen, so long as they couldn't conflict with your actions. I don't know that you could implement the efficient network protocol you would need to do a massive real-time game, however.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess this will work until they invent something better rofl.